# Why does MSVC /I option not find the directory?

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a very basic project structure:

```sh
project
├───lib
│    └───SDL
│         └───SDL.h
├───src
│    └───Main.cpp
```

```c
// Main.cpp
#include <SDL\SDL.h>
int main() {}
```

From the `project` directory I run the command `CL /I\lib src\Main.cpp`, which says `src\Main.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDL\SDL.h': No such file or directory`. I expected the compiler to find SDL.h since I have added `/I\lib`, but it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to drop the \ because this means an absolute path meaning at the root of your filesystem.

Comment: Have you tried `CL /I.\lib src\Main.cpp`? `\lib` looks like an absolut path on current drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
/I.\lib
```

or:

```
/Ilib
```

To refer to a relative path.